# Selection minimum out of $n$ different objects!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, combinations

Suppose we have $n$ differnt persons and $n$ different objects.They have to select from the the objects such that every pair of person has at least one uncommon object.
What is the minimum number of objects that they should select?
**EDIT**
Its also given that every person can select *as many objects as he wants*.
But every pair should have at least one uncommon object each.
So find the total minimum number of objects that they *should* select out of n.
**CLARIFICATION**
For ever pair of person $A$ and $B$, $A$ must have an object that $B$ doesn't have and $B$ must have an object that $A$ doesnt have.
**EXAMPLE**
For $n=5$ there are $5$ persons $\{A,B,C,D,E\}$ and objects numbered $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
The min. number of objects they should select is $4$.
$$\begin{align*}
A: & (3,1)\\
B: & (3,2)\\
C: & (3,4)\\
D: & (4,1)\\
E: & (1,2)
\end{align*}$$
This is one possible combination, but the minimum total is $4$ elements.

Comment: $1$? If person $i$ selects object $i$, we are done. Or are you realting to the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)?

Comment: @AlexR nopes! i have reframed the question .have a look.!

Comment: Still, this is much closer to [tag:probability], than to [tag:combinatorics].

Comment: @AlexR any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the original comment by @Alex. If person $i$ selects object $i$, then each person in a pair has an object the other person in the pair doesn't have. Clarification needed.

Comment: Or maybe you mean this: if you have $n=8$ people, then each one can select a different subset of the first three objects, and then for each pair of people there will be at least one object they don't both have, so collectively they only have to choose 3 objects. But if that's what you want, then the answer is surely just the base-2 logarithm of $n$, rounded up to the nearest integer.

Comment: i m gonna clarify this through an example.wait for it

Comment: go through the example..i hope i have made myself clear this time around

Comment: @GerryMyerson how to approach this now?

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh please use a line delimiter (two spaces at the end of a line, followed by a new line). This is extremely hard to read.

Comment: @AlexR my bad i l be taking that into consideration from next tym for sure

Answer (score 0):

### Reformulating the question to match the example (OP: copy this if it's correct)

For a number of $n$ persons, who pick a number of Objects $A_i \subset \Omega$.
What is the minimum number of elements of $\Omega$, such that the persons can pick objects fulfilling the following condition?
$$A_i \setminus A_j \neq \emptyset \qquad \forall\ i \neq j \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$$

---

### Ansatz based on Michaels' observations

Let $N$ be even, so we don't have to worry about $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$. Then we want
$$\begin{align*}n \lesssim \binom{N}{N/2} & = \frac{N(N-1)(N-2) \ldots (N/2)}{(N/2)(N/2 - 1) \ldots} \\
& = \prod_{k=0}^{N/2-1} \frac{N-k}{N/2 - k} = 2^{N/2} \prod_{k=1}^{N/2-1} \frac{N-k}{N-2k} \\
& = 2^{N/2} \prod_{k=1}^{N/2 - 1} \left(1 + \frac{k}{N-2k}\right)
\end{align*}$$
Where $\lesssim$ denotes, that $N$ should be chosen such, that $N-1$ doesn't fulfill the $<$ restriction, but $N$ does.

Comment: so how to solve this
?

Comment: Edited to put a little thought into it. We need to find a good representation of the product. Either by recursion, or by explicit evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

In OP's example, there could be person $F$ with objects 2 and 4.
So there are ${4\choose 2}$ people choosing two from four objects.

Suppose there are $N$ objects, and everyone chooses $k$ objects.

To answer the opposite question from the OP, what is the maximum number of people that can choose from $N$ objects, it would be ${N\choose\lfloor N/2 \rfloor}$ people.